# How to only call functions once if user presses it multiple times

Tags: python, function, user-interface

I am currently working on a program which has a simply GUI and 3  buttons. One of them is `start`, which runs my code. I am trying to make it as user friendly as possible, so if they spam click it it only runs once. Currently, if the user presses the button multiple times, then the images update multiple times a second.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well its hard to say without knowing anything about your gui but you could disable the button when pressed then run then run the event

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common OOP practices is to view everything in your GUI as a component, a class, which handles its own variables, a component state, which you initialize when you first render the component.

For example, if we want to monitor when a button is clicked, we could disable the button afterwards by updating the component state.

```
class Button:
    """
        Button that self monitors how many clicks have been performed
    """
    def __init__(self,):
        #Initialize state
        self.disabled = False
        self.button_clicked = 0
    
    def click(self,):
        if not self.disabled: #Only perform action if self.disabled == False
            self.disabled = True
            self.button_clicked += 1
            #Do stuff on click

class ButtonContainer:
    """
        Container for a group of associated Buttons
    """

    def __init__(self,):
        self.button1 = Button()
        self.button2 = Button()
        self.button3 = Button()


class App:
    def __init__(self,):
        #Add components to your app
        self.button_container = ButtonContainer()
```

The reason we may want to use a container is because we can group buttons together and monitor then from our main App class.
For example, within the App class we can call

```
print(self.button_container.button1.disabled)
```

With this we can see component states outside of the actual component.

Answer (score 0):

use an if-else statement

```
pressed = 0
```

Then pay attention to the times it was clicked and use

```
if pressed == 3:
    # do this
else:
    # do something different
```